# Why can't Kunkka equip a Quelling Blade?

Tags: dota-2, dota

What is the reason behind this? Does giving *Kunkka* a **Quelling Blade** makes the game unbalanced?

Also, does this same rule carry-over in **Dota2**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Warcraft 3 DotA, Kunkka can't equip it. There is a bug with his splash, bonus damage from Quelling Blade damages opponent heroes as well.

Yes, he can equip it in Dota 2, where the bug is fixed.